# HTML5 canvas drawImage using points?

Tags: html, canvas, html5-canvas

I need to draw an image using 4 points. I have these 4 points stored in an array, these positions changes. Now I need to draw an image that reflects these positions. The context.drawImage only accepts 1 positon.

It should be like this, 4 positions:

```
x,y----------x,y
 |            |
 |            |
 |            |
 |            |
 |            |
x,y----------x,y
```

Comment: So to clarify I understand you correctly, the image has a chance of being askew, not perfectly square?

Comment: Not perfectly square, correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are looking for is called drawing a quad in 3D rendering language.

You usually split up your shape to 2 triangles (faces) and draw them individually using a texture filling.

Here is a (complex) solution for the problem: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/src/renderers/CanvasRenderer.js#L838 Three.js 3D engine using 2D `<canvas>` as the rendering engine.

As the matter is not that straightforward I suggest you use Three.js or similar wrapper which provides high level abstraction over textured face operations. Check out other Three.js 2D `<canvas>` examples and you get the idea how it works:

http://mrdoob.github.com/three.js/

Comment: Fixed link (I checked that the original link pointed to a function called patternPath back when it was posted): https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/r91/examples/js/renderers/CanvasRenderer.js#L917

Comment: how would you do this if it was not askew, but tilted at an angle?

Comment: This answer is more than 10 years old. I do not remember anymore how to code.

Answer (score 7):

## Quad Warping is what you need, no complex 3D

You are asking to render a rectangular image to a, possible non rectangular, quad.

The correct way to do this is to calculate the transformation matrix, no need to render true 3D content. This is done calculating a Homography matrix. For that you need to understand transformation matrices and implement some code for solving some equations.

This process is well understood and requires the original four coordinates and the target four points and you have them, so you only need a process to calculate the transform matrix. This matrix is calculated basically by Gauss-Jordan elimination.

[Check this](http://forum.openframeworks.cc/t/quad-warping-homography-without-opencv/3121/15) on the matrix solver and the general procedure. Once you understand transformations it gets trivial to do it. Also [check this to understand what a homography is](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/494238/how-to-compute-homography-matrix-h-from-corresponding-points-2d-2d-planar-homog). And [here it's explained how it's calculated](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/296794/finding-the-transform-matrix-from-4-projected-points-with-javascript), with samples for javascript and CSS.

### Demo

[Here's an awesome demo](http://franklinta.com/2014/09/08/computing-css-matrix3d-transforms/) with source and explanation.
[image: Quad Warping in Javascript]

Comment: Great demo link +1 Awesome stuff :o

Comment: There's actually two ways (at least) to map a quad to a rectangle. The other one I know is *bilinear interpolation*. That's what people without enough math logic sometimes come up with when they try to implement it intuitively but it distorts diagonals into curves.