# HTML5 canvas, image on/in polygon possible?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

Is there a way using javascript html5 canvas, to have a polygon and then display an image in it instead of a color?

Comment: short answer: yes. what did you try?

Comment: I've tried using context.drawImage but I can't specify all four x,y positions using this method I think

Comment: I remember your [other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10660521/html5-canvas-drawimage-using-points), which this is likely a duplicate of..  but I did do few hours worth of research on it.  It is possible.. if you want to clip an image.  I am unsure if it is possible if you want to **manipulate** the image.

Comment: @Joseph what's the OP supposed to have tried? The docs of `drawImage` say nothing about polygons, and the docs about `fillStyle` say nothing about images. I believe something about cropping or setting polygonal bounds might exist, but without knowing of it beforehand there's nothing that could be tried.

Comment: @mgibsonbr there are a lot of tutorials if you Google 'em.

Comment: @Joseph fair enough, though I doubt this is something a beginner material would show. I've read a lot a lot about html5 canvas and didn't know the answer to this question until today.

Comment: [Stack Overflow is not your personal research assistant](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128553/177538). You should show what you have tried so people will guide you, not Google for you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After some research, I believe it's possible to do that by first creating a pattern using your image, then setting that pattern to `fillStyle`:

```
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var pattern = ctx.createPattern(imageObj, "repeat");
ctx.fillStyle = pattern;
```

Then it's just a matter of creating your polygon (using `moveTo` and `lineTo`) and then filling it normally.

Source: [this plugin](http://blogfreakz.com/jquery/polyclip-js-clip-jpeg-images-into-polygons/)'s source code. Disclaimer: haven't tried it myself to confirm that works.

**Update:** I'm still investigating whether or not you can manipulate the image to fit an arbitrary polygon. In principle, you could use [`setTransform`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Canvas_tutorial/Transformations) to do that:

```
ctx.save();
ctx.setTransform(m11, m12, m21, m22, dx, dy);
ctx.drawImage(imageObj);
ctx.restore();
```

Determining the values of `setTransform` parameters (if it's possible to do that at all) is the tricky part. It's been looong since I did **any** math, but if I recall correctly here's what needs to be done:

```
(0,0) --- (w,0)       (x1,y1) --- (x2,y2)
  |         |            |           |
  |  Image  |     =>     |  Morphed  |
  |         |            |           |
(0,h) --- (w,h)       (x3,y3) --- (x4,y4)
```

For each point, you'd do the following matrix operation:

```
|m11 m21 dx|   |xI|   |xM|
|m12 m22 dy| X |yI| = |yM|
| 0   0   1|   | 1|   | 1|
```

Eight equations, six variables (remembering that the matrix elements are the variables, the rest are constants - our inputs). Might be unsolvable. Now it's only a matter of deducing (or googling, or asking in Math.SE...) and implementing the formulas for each parameter...

**Update 2:** Although I don't have hard evidence of that, I believe it's impossible to do what you want with `setTransform`. Looking at how Gimp does with its "perspective" tool, it's necessary to change also the third row of the transform matrix to transform your image to an arbitrary polygon. And the Canvas API does not seem to provide means for that (usually only affine transformations are supported: translation, rotation, scale, shear or a combination of above).

Quoting [this post](http://www.useragentman.com/blog/2011/01/07/css3-matrix-transform-for-the-mathematically-challenged/) on 2D transforms:

> CSS3 2D-Transforms can only transform blocks into parallelograms. For example, it is impossible to transform a block into this shape:
>   [Irregular Shape]
>   In order to do this, one must use CSS3 3D Transforms. This is why the Matrix Construction Set only has three control points to drag around, not four.

There are plans for [CSS 3D Transforms](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-3d-transforms/), but not only I don't know how widely supported that is, I dunno if the canvas element (with 2d context, that is - WebGL is another story) will ever support it. In short, it's not possible to do what you want through any means I know of.

Comment: I'm truly unsure if this is what the OP wants; I would recommend you view my comment on their question.

Comment: @Daedalus yes, I've read your comments (both here and in the duplicate), I'm answering because: a) it might be indeed what the OP wants; b) I didn't know about that until today, and that's something I'm interested in too. Anyway, I'll research on the subject a little further, it might be possible to do some manipulation too using the context's transform.

Comment: Great method though it does not follow each objects' own positions. It makes it look like each object are trasparent and you can see the background.

Comment: @Forested I'm not sure what you meant with that. Do you want to deform (morph) the images, so each vertex in the original image will map to a vertex in the resulting polygon? (the points in-between following around) If that's the case, see my update, I still haven't got a good answer for that. If it's something else, please clarify.

Comment: Yes it's what you're currently looking into!

Comment: @Forested in that case, I have bad news for you... check my updated answer

Answer (score 4):

You can fill a polygon with an image using `context.clip()`:

```
  //create an image
  var img = new Image();
  img.src = 'imgPath/image.png'

  //draw the image when loaded
  img.onload = function(){
      var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
      ctx.save();

      //define the polygon
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.moveTo(x1,y1);
      ctx.lineTo(x2,y2);
      ctx.lineTo(x3,y3);
      ctx.closePath();

      //draw the image
      ctx.clip();
      ctx.drawImage(img, leftMostXCoor, highestYCoor, polyWidth, polyHeight);

      //fill and stroke are still available for overlays and borders
      ctx.fill();
      ctx.stroke();

      ctx.restore();
  }
```

Comment: This is not drawing a texture on a polygon. This clips the image to that polygon...

Answer (score 0):

If you only want regular polygons then you could use this CSS only tool instead of canvas (disclaimer, I wrote it) https://html-polygon.com

Although it is built for React and Vue only, you can use the play tool on that site and grab the resulting HTML.