# Canvas Image resize / scew / dnd

Tags: javascript, canvas, three.js, webgl

I'm trying to build a application where people can upload images and I want to make it possible that people can drag the corners of the image and distort it. But I have no clue where to start and I can't find any examples.

I do have an example in flash: http://configurator.cando.eu/popup.html
- Click "Cando Stijlkamer"
- Click on 1 of the 6 backgrounds
- On the top select step 2 "Kies uw deur"
- Double click the door, and on the bottom do it again.
- Now you can drag the corners.

Example image:
[image: Distort image]

Anyone knows how to make this possible?

**UPDATE**
Started using ThreeJS for webGL, at the moment I got a cube, can make it perspective, scale and scew it. But the corner wont be flexible.

**UPDATE 2**
Created a custom geometry with draggable corners.

Comment: Doing real-time distortion effects like that looks more like a use-case for WebGL.

Comment: @Philipp: +1 for pointing away from canvas or svg because their 3x3 transform matrices wouldn't support non-parallel distortion.

Comment: Like @Philipp says it's a thing for WebGL. Your question looks the same as: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10660521/html5-canvas-drawimage-using-points check that.

Comment: I've started using ThreeJS, got a lot made possible, except for the Geometry, do I need to create my own Geometry on render?

Comment: @Niels can you share an example of your solution? Or point me in the right direction? I'm also looking for the same.

Answer (score 2):

I can show you how you can do this effect very easy in Flash. However, if you need to use HTML5 I would suggest https://github.com/edankwan/PerspectiveTransform.js instead of Canvas element.